# Need help in understanding a verbatim of the Replacement theorem in Linear Algebra from the book, Linear Algebra, by Stephen H Friedberg,...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

I will start with enumerating some definitions, which I use in Linear Algebra:

- The basis for a vector space $V$ is defined as a subset $S$ of $V$ such that $\text{span}(S)=V$ and $S$ is a linearly independent subset of $V.$
- If $S$ is a finite basis for $V$ then if, $W$ is another basis for $V$ we have, $|V|=|W|.$
- Finally, if a vector space $V$ have, a finite basis $S$ then, the $V$ is said to have a finite dimension with dimension of $V$ defined to be equal to the number of vectors in $S.$ The finute dimension of $V$ is generally denoted as $\dim (S).$
- If $V$ is not of a finite -dimension then $V$ is called infinite dimensional.

---

Next, I state a theorem.

The Replacement Formula in Linear Algebra, says that,

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $G$ be a generating set of $V$ having exactly $n$ elements. If $L$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$ having exactly $m$ elements then, we have, $m\leq n$ and $\exists H\subseteq G$ having exactly $n-m$ elements such that, $L\cup H$ spans $V.$

---

Now, in the book "Linear Algebra " by Stephen H Friedberg, Insel and Spence,(4th Edition), Chapter-1, Pg- 47 (Section-1.6 titled Bases and Dimension)  there was a piece of text written as below:

> In the terminology of dimension, the first conclusion in the replacement
> theorem states that if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, then no linearly
> independent subset of $V$ can contain more than $\dim(V)$ vectors.

But I am doubting this line. This is because of a couple of unclear issues, I am facing. Let's analyze this sentence, part by part:

- They start the sentence by saying, "In the terminology of dimension, the first conclusion in the replacement
  theorem states that if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector..." and in here, it's clear that the first conclusion of the replacement theorem refers to the fact:

*Let $V$ be a vector space and let $G$ be a generating set of $V$ having exactly $n$ elements. If $L$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$ having exactly $m$ elements then, we have, $m\leq n.$*

Moreover, $V$  is a finite-dimensional vector means, that the basis for $V$, which is also a generating set of $V$ say, $S$ is finite. With respect to the theorem we have, $G=S.$

- Next, they goes on as, "... then no linearly independent subset of $V$ can contain more than $\dim(V)$ vectors." This means, if $L$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$ then, it is finite and has no more than $\dim(V)=|S|$ vectors.

But here's the problem. The replacement theorem says, specifically, **if** $L$ is a linearly independent set having exactly $m$ elements then, $m\leq n.$

In this case, $n=|S|.$ We can never say, $|L|\leq n.$ This is because, **no information** regarding the finiteness of $L$ is given. It may happen that, $L$ is an infinite set and then, the given statement is clearly incorrect. The statement is true, only if, $L$ is finite say, has $m(\in\Bbb N)$ number of elements as, this is when, **we can correctly apply Replacement Theorem** to conclude, $m\leq n.$

But then again, I doubt whether the below assertion is valid:

> If $V$ is a vector space that have a finite dimension, then all linearly independent subset of $V$ is finite.

If the above claim is true, then only the statement given in the book, holds true. But otherwise,  I feel that the statement is incorrect.

I need some help with this issue.

Comment: You have that $L$ is a linearly independent set of elements of $V$, which is a finite dimensional vector space. In these circumstances $L$ must be finite - you can't have an infinite linearly independent set of elements of a finite dimensional space. This is probably implicit in the proof anyway, even if not stated.

Comment: To add onto @MarkBennet's answer: Friedberg, Axler, and similar level books usually do their proofs for finite dimensions and they explicitly state when something holds in the infinite case as well.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks! But how to prove that fact, i.e a finite dimensional vector space cannot have an infinte linearly independent set ?

Comment: @ThomasFinley That is directly from the definition of a finite dimensional vector space: it has a finite linearly independent set as a basis.

Comment: @trivialmathisdifficult Can you check my answer below. Is this what you intended?

Comment: @MarkBennet I have posted an answer below. If you don't mind, can you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement given in the book is completely correct and justified.

The assertion

> If $V$ is a vector space that have a finite dimension, then all linearly independent subset of $V$ is finite.

towards the end of the OP is a valid claim which can be proved.

We give the proof of this claim as follows:

The Replacement Theorem says, that a finite linearly independent subset of $V$ has at most $\dim V$ vectors. Now, an infinite linearly independent set, has more than $\dim V$ vectors.

This implies we can find a subset, say $H$ of the infinite linearly independent set (say, $S'$ ) having more than $\dim V$ vectors. We note that, $H$ will be linearly independent as well. By the Replacement Theorem, the number of vectors in $H$ is less than or equal to $\dim V.$ This is clearly a contradiction.

Thus, such an $H$ does not exist, which in turn implies that no  infinite linearly independent subset of V i.e $S'$ existed in the first place.

**So, all linearly independent subset of $V$ is finite.**

Comment: I feel like saying a infinite set cannot be a subset of a finite set is enough, but sure.

Comment: @trivialmathisdifficult Ah, ok but is my solution good to go?

Comment: @ThomasFinley I think what the OP said, and I happen to agree with, is the statement of the replacement theorem (Theorem 1.10) in the book by Friedberg et al, only says any "finite" linearly independent subset of the vector space. Of course, as we know any (finite) subset of a linearly independent set is linearly independent, so you asserted and proved, in a finite dimensional vector space one cannot have an infinite linearly independent subset. For teaching or self-learning reasons, I would add a little corollary or remark which states what you asserted right after the replacement theorem.